# Redirect domain/* to index.html using .htacesss

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, wildcard

I have an external domain `example.com` pointing to my ip in the GCP. Its a new server set up and has `index.html` file in the `var/www/html` folder. I want any URL of pattern `example.com/<any 6 digit unique string>` to call the `index.html` file. I tried adding below rule in the `.htaccess` file and placed in the same folder as `index.html` (`/var/www/html`). Only the URL `example.com` is rendering the `index.html` file but the URL `example.com/ha36hja` is showing a "not found" error.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://example.com(.*)$ index.html [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: You mention a "6 digit unique string" but your example shows `subdomain.com/ha36hja` which contains a path component with a string that certainly is not compose of only digits ...

Comment: Have you turned on `.htaccess` files with `AllowOverride` in your Apache conf?

Comment: And `example.com/ha36hja` comprises a URL-path of 7 characters, not 6?

Comment: modified the apache.config file and htaccess to below. After modification getting site cannot be reached error  `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+{0,6}$ index.html [R=301,NC]`    and apache.config  `<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: You need to update your question with that information. But those mod_rewrite directives don't make sense (particularly with the inconsistent information in the question). "site cannot be reached" is very different to "not found". But you also now appear to be editing the server config, not `.htaccess`? `RewriteBase` certainly has no place in a _server_ context and will break your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_/]{0,6}$ index.html [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Tried with this but still getting error "the requested  url was not found  on this server.